# How to populate combobox with mysql database stored procedures

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, combobox

I have a winform with lables and textboxes to save data to mysql database, and I added a combobox to retrieve information from my stored procedure which displays 2 columns ID and Names. My question is how do I populate my combobox1 with results of my stored procedures.
 below is my c# code

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `sms_pigen`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_clearing_agent`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_clearing_agent`()
BEGIN
SELECT clearing_agent_id, clearing_agent_name
FROM tms_clearing_agents;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

```
public partial class frmNewClient : Form
{
    MySqlConnection connection;
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySqlDataAdapter adp;
    DataSet cb = new DataSet();
    public frmNewClient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmNewClient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pigen"].ConnectionString;

    //    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    //    connection.Open();

    //    DataSet cb = new DataSet();

    }

    private void btnSubmitClients_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pigen"].ConnectionString;

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            string CmdText = "INSERT INTO t_pi_Clients(ClientCode,ClientName,PostalAdd,Telephone,Fax,EmailAdd1,EmailAdd2,EmailAdd3,Website,TotalDeposit,AccountBal,ChargeRate)VALUES(@ClientCode, @ClientName, @PostalAdd, @Telephone, @Fax, @EmailAdd1, @EmailAdd2, @EmailAdd3, @Website, @TotalDeposit, @AccountBal, @ChargeRate)";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(CmdText, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientCode", txtboxClientCode.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientName", txtboxClientName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostalAdd", txtboxPostalAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", txtboxTelephone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fax", txtboxFax.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdd1", txtboxEmailAddress1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdd2", txtboxEmailAddress2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdd3", txtboxEmailAddress3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Website", txtboxWebsite.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalDeposit", txtboxTotalDepo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountBal", txtboxAccountBal.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChargeRate", txtboxChargeRate.Text);

            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Entry Saved");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Form_Load command you create the connection and the command to retrieve your data through the storedprocedure. Is essential to set the CommandType to StoredProcedure and then pass this command to an MySqlDataAdapter as the SelectCommand. After retrieving data with Fill you set the DataTable as Datasource for the combobox and set the DisplayMember and ValueMember to the appropriate fields of the table.

```
private void frmNewClient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pigen"].ConnectionString;
    using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_clearing_agent";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using(MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
            combobox.DisplayMember = "clearing_agent_name";
            combobox.ValueMember = "clearing_agent_id";
            combobox.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you shouldn't keep global objects like the connection and the adapters. Create them when you need them and destroy them immediately after you have used them

Comment: thanks for ur effort and feedback i'll try and give feedback....i'll keep that in mind too

Answer (score 0):

here is code to retrieve data from Store procedure and Bind data to comboBox

```
        DataTable dtTest = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText="sp_clearing_agent";
        cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter sdaTest = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dsTest=new DataSet();
        sdaTest.Fill(dsTest);
        //binding data to combobox
        cmbTest.DataSource = dsTest.Tables[0];
        comboBox1.DataSource.DisplayMember="clearing_agent_id"
        comboBox1.DataSource.ValueMember="clearing_agent_name"
        comboBox1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: ur code does work out well tanxs for ur effort once more i appreciate it but i might have to select steve's solution which is more precise and exactly what i needed ty